# How to allow write permissions on Ubuntu server?

Tags: ubuntu, permissions, vps

I am trying to install [MCHostPanel from github](https://github.com/Alanaktion/MCHostPanel)
but after finishing installation proccess on a website, it didn't let me login with my login details so I checked the apache2 log and I got this output:

```
[Sat Jul 30 09:00:46.063745 2022] [php7:warn] [pid 444] [client mywebsite.com:62027] PHP Warning:  file_put_contents(data/users/jox.json): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /var/www/html/inc/lib.php on line 586, referer: http://mywebsite.com/install.php
[Sat Jul 30 09:00:46.063797 2022] [php7:warn] [pid 444] [client mywebsite.com:62027] PHP Warning:  file_put_contents(.installed): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /var/www/html/install.php on line 9, referer: http://mywebsite.com/install.php
```

now, `data/users/jox.json` is the user I created as an admin user but it's not in my data/users folder obviously.

How can I fix this?
Their github issues doesn't seem to be active for quite a long time so didn't bother to write there as it's an issue on my vps' end.

VPS: Ubuntu 18.04 64bit

Edit: I forgot to add the line of codes where error occures.

`install.php`

line 2-11

```
require_once 'inc/lib.php';

$installed = is_file(__DIR__ . '/.installed');

if (!$installed && !empty($_POST['user'])) {
    session_start();
    user_add($_POST['user'], $_POST['pass'], 'admin', $_POST['dir'], $_POST['ram'], $_POST['port']);
    file_put_contents(".installed", ""); // <------------- **Line 9**
    $_SESSION['user'] = clean_alphanum($_POST['user']);
}
```

This is `/inc/lib.php`

```
    // Write to file
    file_put_contents('data/users/' . strtolower(clean_alphanum($user['user'])) . '.json', json_encode($user));
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to use the authorized user, or change your user to get root access

you need to see what user you are using to run

for example you use www, use usermod -G root www
then
set www to get root access
add
www ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL
etc/sudoers